$\mathcal{E}_t := \sigma(\tau \wedge s, s \leq t)$ for $\tau$ a real random variable
Let consider $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ a probability space and $\tau$ a real random variable. Set $\mathcal{E}_t := \sigma(\tau \wedge s, s \leq t)$ the $\sigma-$algebra generated by the random variables $\tau \wedge s$, $s \leq t$.
My question is the following

Is it straighforward that $\{\tau > t\} \in \mathcal{E}_t$ ?

I can see that $\{\tau \geq t\} = \{\tau \wedge t = t\} \in \mathcal{E}_t$ but I am maybe missing something for $\{\tau > t\}$.

This is false. Define $X:\Omega\rightarrow\{1,2\}$ with $P[X=1]=P[X=2]=1/2$. Use $t=1$. Then
$$ \min[X,s] = s \quad \forall s \leq 1$$
Therefore
$$ \sigma(\min[X,s], s\leq 1) = \sigma(s, s\leq 1) = \{\phi, \Omega\}$$
So this sigma algebra does not allow you to distinguish whether or not $X>1$. Specifically, $\{X>1\} \notin \{\phi, \Omega\}$.
